# Spring MVC 3 Validation - Unable to find a default provider

Tags: java, validation, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I get an error when trying to set up Spring MVC validation.

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
```

I read in the documents that the default provider they use is the hibernate-validator.  Do I need to include this library to get validation to work?  Is it okay to include this library even though i'm not using hibernate for my project?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you should include Hibernate Validator library in order to use it. It doesn't depend on Hibernate itself.

Answer (score 44):

If you are using Maven, you must add a dependency to the **Hibernate Validator Annotation Processor**.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find it in the **JBoss repository** :

```
<repository>
  <id>JBoss Repository</id>
  <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  <name>JBoss Repository</name>
</repository>
```

Comment: Only use "hibernate-validator", not "hibernate-validator-annotation-processor", the latter adds more to the project than you need.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using Hibernate 4.