# GWT doesn´t find my persistence.xml

Tags: gwt, hibernate-validator

I´m trying to save a simple user in my jpa hibernate db.
So I have a persistence.xml that **I know that works** (If I execute a simple test without deploying the gwt app).

The problem is that when I test it with my user interface, the persist method throw me the next error: (I think this is cause Doesn´t find the persistence.xml)

> [ERROR] javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: isw2.tasks] Unable to >configure EntityManagerFactory
>
> ... bla bla bla
>
> [ERROR] Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to get the default Bean >Validation factory
>
> ... more bla bla bla..
>
> [ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> ...
>   [ERROR] Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory

[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:383)

[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:109)

.....

[ERROR] Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider

[ERROR]     at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)

[ERROR]     at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)

[ERROR]     at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.ja

This is the method I know that works:

`EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("isw2.tasks");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.persist(u);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.clear();
    em.close();
```

`

And the most usefull for us,  my proyect skeleton: (See that the persistence.xml file is there!)

[image]

I´m using maven and deploying the web app with the codehaus plugin.

Thanks in advance experts ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message `Unable to find a default provider` suggests that hibernate cannot find a validation provider.

Is your Hibernate Validator jar on your runtime classpath? Also do note that you need to [use Hibernate Validator 4 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982950/javax-validation-validationexception-unable-to-find-default-provider).

Comment: Oh! It was this!, I was using Hibernate Validator 3.1  instead the last version. Thanks you for your time @Tahir.