# Idea IntelliJ. how creating maven project. what about pom.xml and .iml files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

i just started with java, and created a project.
its maven project (i hadn't use maven yet)

so my project have two modules A and B.
and B depends on A, and A depends on some from remote maven repo. and B also depends on some remote repo.
its works fine in Idea IntelliJ and build jars fine.

but afaik .iml files are Idea IntelliJ specific. and pom.xml is maven specific.
and when i inspect files why all depedecy of project is written in .iml files and .idea dir instead of pom.xml(s)

if you want to see the real world source then [here](https://github.com/dev-meghraj/WebTrimmer) it is but its alpha project for learning java deeply.
and when i try to build project on [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/dev-meghraj/WebTrimmer) it unable to resolve dependencies of project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meghraj,

I have forked your WebTrimmer repo here : https://github.com/ajorpheus/WebTrimmer and fixed a couple of issues which were preventing a successful build:

1. The travisci fails because you have three jars in the lib folder which are not available to the CI since it's doing a maven build. 
   The fix was to remove those three jars and introduce corresponding maven dependencies as in [this](https://github.com/ajorpheus/WebTrimmer/commit/e5fbc995d9b576dd95dbb1158f4e14a71cda4c78) commit.
2. While adding the maven dependencies an exclusion was needed as noted here : [The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908651/the-following-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved-javax-jmsjmsjar1-1)
3. The WebTrimmerUI depends on the classes in it's sibling module WebTrimmerEngine, therefore a corresponding dependency is needed.

I have converted the project into a pure maven project which is IDE-agnostic. With the above changes, I can build the project from command line and expect that the travisci should be able to as well.

Regarding the question about why the dependencies are duplicated in .iml --- That's not the reason the CI job fails. The dependencies in that file are a snapshot of the dependencies in the pom.xml. This snapshot is updated when the maven project is re-imported manually by the user, or automatically if the maven project is set to 'Auto-Import'.
As Peter Lawrey mentioned in his comment above, if you add a jar to the project, maven does not know about it and it will be present only in the .iml file.

In general, to search and add a maven dependency, the following has always worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178586/325742

Hope this helps !

Comment: hi Jindal, i am really thankfull to you, as you know i don't want my project to IDE-agnostic, so now i try to do re-import in IDEA but that didn't write dependecies in pom.xml

Comment: and please don't remove your forked repo, until i merge it, you know i am newbie still learning.

Comment: Ok. If you import my forked version into Intellij it should work fine.

Comment: cool, the repo is public and I won't remove it. Let me know when you are done.

Comment: i have zipped and saved your changes now, but how do i merge your repo's code into mine without going onto cmd line, within github or ide

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dependencies to the pom yourself. The .iml files are for storing project specific settings for whatever project you are currently working on.

Having the pom files allows your maven builds to be IDE independent where as the .iml files require you to have IntelliJ.

You can exclude the .iml files from and version control you are using. You can also open an existing maven project directly via IntelliJ by opening its pom.xml and IntelliJ can auto import everything specified in the pom file and will generate new .iml files.

Comment: isn't there is automation thing, if IDE know all dependecy well and build project well, even it have to be configure through 'project structer' area then what all that means

Comment: so why Idea says its support maven

Comment: It does support maven.

Comment: what do you mean why?

Comment: means what kind of functions related to maven we can use with Idea, if it can't write pom.xmls files so what other features that we want

Comment: Ok you need to honestly go read some basic maven tutorials, I've flagged this to be closed for lack of basic understanding.

Comment: please consider removing your answer, because i don't think and we have write to pox.xml manually

Comment: You right click on the class and use the context menu then to add maven dependency. Also, reword your original question as that isn't what you were asking.

Comment: can you please share those links with me

Comment: i asking that why idea storing dependeny in other files instead of pom.xml even its maven project that idea supports

Comment: I have found that the add dependency option only adds them to the project not pom.xml, I suspect a bug.  I always edit the pom.xml and import it instead.