# Intellij IDEA does not update pom.xml file

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I just created a blank Java Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5 (I didn't select an archetype), it's a console app. After adding a library dependency via Maven dialog, it was added to .iml file but not to the pom.xml. So if I run `mvn package` either from IDEA or command line it can't find the dependency. 
What did I do wrong? (just starting to work with JVM/Java)

Comment: Why didn't you add the dependency directly to the POM?

Comment: Just add a `<dependency>` to your `pom.xml` and click Re-import in the Maven view.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv you mean an empty `dependencies` tag? just tried that, it does not work

Comment: @chester89 no, empty `<dependencies>` gives nothing. Add the latter and put a new `<dependency>` element with properly configured `<groupId>`, `<artifactId>`, and `<version>`. IntelliJ won't add it for you as far as I know.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I see. so I have to do that for every library I add?

Comment: I'm used to add them manually. :) This may help you: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/generating-maven-dependencies.html

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv I guess they are synchronized in opposite direction - once you change pom.xml, IDEA will update .iml file

Comment: @chester89 yes, that's true. If you have auto-import enabled, it's automatic; otherwise you have to click "Reimport All Maven Projects".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328382/how-to-convert-iml-into-pom-including-dependencies#comment54455422_33328382 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806961/idea-intellij-how-creating-maven-project-what-about-pom-xml-and-iml-files linked there. In particular: „_You need to add dependencies to the pom yourself._“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea doesn't work like that. You should go to edit the pom, create a dependencies tag, and within that hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>insert</kbd> (standard key bindings). This will give you some help in creating your dependency.

Alternatively you could just find your dependency in a browser from mvnrepo.org or some other place, and copy/paste the dependency into your dependencies section. Reimporting the maven project will then fix everything -- Intellij will download the required dependency and ensure its referenced within the IDE.

Comment: That's the answer it seems, but I agree with the OP - correcting an unknown type IntelliJ detects that it's declared in a different module and offers to "add dependency" for that module - it's reasonable that it should add it to the pom in a maven project